# Pyspark - Flattening a list of dictionaries (piplelinedRDD) into a single dictionary and grouping by values by key

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by, pyspark, rdd

I have a list of dictionaries stored in a piplelinedRDD looking something like this:

```
[{ZDX: ID_42, XCZ: ID_32, ZXD: ID_434}, {ZDX: ID_69, XXF: ID_30, HGL: ID_239, XCZ: ID_01}]
```

I want to produce an output that looks like this

```
{ZDX: [ID_42, ID_69], XCZ: [ID_32, ID_01], ZXD: [ID_434], XXF: [ID_30], HGL :[ID_239]}
```

Since it is stored in a pipelinedRDD, the dictionary is not iterable either.

Comment: What do you mean by "the dictionary is not iterable"?

Comment: Sorry I meant the piplelinedRDD is not iterable and will throw an error if you try to iterate through it

Comment: What about using `foreach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used integers as values of the dictionary, if you have strings the procedure is the same.

Starting RDD

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([{'ZDX': 42, 'XCZ': 32, 'XD': 434}, {'ZDX': 69, 'XXF': 30, 'HGL': 239, 'XCZ': 1}])
```

Create a RDD with tuples which represents your pair (key,values):

```
>>> items = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: (line.items()))
>>> items.take(items.count())
[('XCZ', 32),('ZDX', 42), ('XD', 434), ('XCZ', 1),('HGL', 239),('ZDX', 69),('XXF', 30)]
```

Group by key:

```
>>> groupedItems = items.groupByKey().mapValues(list)
>>> groupedItems.take(groupedItems.count())
>>> [('XCZ', [32, 1]),('ZDX', [42, 69]), ('XXF', [30]),('HGL', [239]), ('XD', [434])]
```

Use [collectAsMap](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.collectAsMap) in order to get a dictionary from your RDD

```
>>> d = groupedItems.collectAsMap()
>>> {'HGL': [239], 'XCZ': [32, 1], 'XD': [434], 'XXF': [30], 'ZDX': [42, 69]}
```